# Using a potentiometer to control a servo HAT

Tags: hardware

I bought the servo hat from Adafruit and a MCP 3008. My goal is to control a servo with a potentiometer with my Raspberry Pi. With a Arduino there is a function called `map`. Is a there a similar way to do this with a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: From memory mapping is one line of code.  Just copy it.

Comment: Copy what? Can you give me an example?

Comment: There is a function called mapping.  Put mapping Arduino code into Google then copy the one line of code.

Comment: I understand how to do this with arduino.  But how do you map with the raspberry pi in python.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You read the MCP3008 to get a number between 0 and 1023.  You feed that number into the map function to get a pulse width in the range 1000 to 2000 µs which you send to the servo.  Exactly the same as an Arduino.